how to make a stacked histogram macro VBA
I want to create an excel macro stacked histogram from a table (4 columns)
Column Z ( identifier )
Column AA (error name)
Column AB (frequency)
AC column (color)
I want the X AXIS sound diagram to take the Values ​​from column Z the identifiers, and the Y axis column AB the frequency and the bars each by its color (which is in column AC) and with a legend which displays each color linked to what error name
Here is my table:

Here is the code I started with:
Set plageDiagrammeT = FeuilleName.Range("Z1:AC" & lastRowIDF)

' Créer le diagramme
Set diagramme = FeuilleName.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=400, Width:=675, Top:=0, Height:=225)
' Configurez le type de graphique
diagramme.Chart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered ' Vous pouvez ajuster le type de graphique si nécessaire

' Définir le type de graphique
With diagramme.Chart
.SetSourceData Source:=plageDiagrammeT, PlotBy:=xlColumns
.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
.HasTitle = True
.ChartTitle.Text = "Titre du Diagramme"
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = FeuilleName.Range("Z2:Z" & lastRowIDF) ' Axe des X
.SetSourceData Source:=FeuilleName.Range("AB2:AB" & lastRowIDF)
.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = FeuilleName.Range("Z2:Z" & lastRowIDF) ' Légende
.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelPosition = xlTickLabelPositionNextToAxis ' Position des étiquettes sur l'axe des X
' Ajouter les valeurs de la colonne AA comme légende
With FeuilleName
For i = 2 To lastRowIDF
If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 27).Value) And Not IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 29).Value) Then
diagramme.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
diagramme.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Name = .Cells(i, 27).Value ' Colonne AA + AC

End If
Next i

End With

End With
' Personnalisez les couleurs des barres
i = 0
For i = 2 To lastRowIDF
Dim colorCode As Long
RGBColor = FeuilleName.Cells(i, 29).Value ' Colonne AC (valeur RGB)
RGBValues = Split(Mid(RGBColor, 5, Len(RGBColor) - 5), ",")
redValue = Trim(RGBValues(0))
greenValue = Trim(RGBValues(1))
blueValue = Trim(RGBValues(2))
diagramme.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(redValue, greenValue, blueValue)
Next i

' Affichez le graphique
diagramme.Activate

This is what it shows me

I was not able to display each bar by its color and the legend it does not group the error names
Please, do you know a way to do this simply and automatically for all the bars of the histogram at once?
Thanks in advance
YRI

What's your expected output?

I would reformat the data to have one column for each error type and the corresponding value in each column.


Merge cells on the first col before creating the chart.
Change the color of Points() instead of SeriesCollection

Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey As String, vRng, sIDF As String
    Dim arrData
    Dim oSht1 As Worksheet, oSht2 As Worksheet
    const COL="Z"  ' modify as needed
    Set oSht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")  ' modify as needed
    oSht1.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    Set oSht2 = ActiveSheet
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set rngData = oSht2.Range(COL & "1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 1)
        If sKey = "" Then
            sKey = sIDF
        Else
            sIDF = sKey
        End If
        If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
            Set objDic(sKey) = Union(oSht2.Cells(i, COL), objDic(sKey))
        Else
            Set objDic(sKey) = oSht2.Cells(i, COL)
        End If
    Next i
    For Each vRng In objDic.Items
        '        Debug.Print vRng.Address
        If vRng.Cells.Count > 1 Then vRng.Merge
    Next
    oSht2.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=rngData.Resize(, rngData.Columns.Count - 1)
    ActiveChart.ClearToMatchStyle
    ActiveChart.ChartStyle = 207
    Dim RGBColor, RGBValues, redValue, greenValue, blueValue
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        Dim colorCode As Long
        RGBColor = arrData(i, 4)
        RGBValues = Split(Mid(RGBColor, 5, Len(RGBColor) - 5), ",")
        redValue = Trim(RGBValues(0))
        greenValue = Trim(RGBValues(1))
        blueValue = Trim(RGBValues(2))
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(i - 1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(redValue, greenValue, blueValue)
    Next i
    Set objDic = Nothing
End Sub




If you're looking for stacked column chart, pivot chart might be a good approach.
The customized color isn't being applied to the chart due to inconsistency in the color scheme within the source table. For instance, ERREUR1 has different setting on row 2 & 3.

Sub ColumnStacked()
    Dim rCell As Range, rngData As Range, blankRng As Range
    Dim oSht1 As Worksheet, oSht2 As Worksheet
    Set oSht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    oSht1.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    Set oSht2 = ActiveSheet
    Set rngData = oSht2.Range("Z1").CurrentRegion
    With rngData
        On Error Resume Next
        Set blankRng = .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        On Error Resume Next
        If Not blankRng Is Nothing Then blankRng.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
    End With
    Dim oPC As PivotCache, oPT As PivotTable
    Set oPC = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rngData, Version:=8)
    Set rCell = rngData.Cells(1).Offset(, rngData.Columns.Count + 2)
    Set oPT = oPC.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=rCell, DefaultVersion:=8)
    With oPT
        .PivotFields("IDF").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("Raison").Orientation = xlColumnField
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("Fréquence"), "Sum of F", xlSum
    End With
    oSht2.Shapes.AddChart2(297, xlColumnStacked).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=oPT.TableRange1
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementLegendRight)
End Sub



Thanks ! i'm testing the second solution it shows me the PivotTable correctly but not the chart ( its empty )

Have u tested the code with the sample data in your post?

actualy the pivotTable is not correct it's data and my result table data doesn't match

i added the output in an answer

This sample code shows property by property how to set them for a stacked column chart. The colors are separated in the three adjacent cells as numbers for easier assignment.
Sub StackChart()
Dim ch As Chart
Set ch = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(1150, 240, 360, 250).Chart   'create a chart object
ch.ChartType = 52                                                 'set type Stacked Column
For i = 2 To 13                                                   'loop through the data rows
    Set newserie = ch.SeriesCollection.Add(Range("A1:A3"), , , False)   'create base series
    If Cells(i, "Z") = "ID1" Then
        newserie.Values = Array(Cells(i, "AB"), 0, 0)                      'assign value to referring column
        newserie.Name = Cells(i, "AA")                                     'set the Legend name
        newserie.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(Cells(i, "AC"), Cells(i, "AD"), Cells(i, "AE"))  'set the color        'set the color of the series
    ElseIf Cells(i, "Z") = "ID2" Then
        newserie.Values = Array(0, Cells(i, "AB"), 0)
        newserie.Name = Cells(i, "AA")
        newserie.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(Cells(i, "AC"), Cells(i, "AD"), Cells(i, "AE"))        'set the color of the series
    Else
        newserie.Values = Array(0, 0, Cells(i, "AB"))
        newserie.Name = Cells(i, "AA")
        newserie.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(Cells(i, "AC"), Cells(i, "AD"), Cells(i, "AE"))        'set the color of the series
    End If
Next i
ch.Axes(xlCategory).CategoryNames = Array("ID1", "ID2", "ID3")    'set Category names or use UNIQUE to  create
End Sub




after testing the secode solution of pivotChart actualy the pivotTable is not correct it's data and my result table data doesn't match
here's my code :
    ' Stacked column chart
 Dim rCell As Range, rngData As Range, blankRng As Range
    
    Set rngData = FeuilleName.Range("Z1").CurrentRegion
    With rngData
        On Error Resume Next
        Set blankRng = .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        On Error Resume Next
        If Not blankRng Is Nothing Then blankRng.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
    End With
    Dim oPC As pivotCache, oPT As pivotTable
    Set oPC = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rngData, Version:=8)
    Set rCell = rngData.Cells(1).Offset(, rngData.Columns.Count + 2)
    Set oPT = oPC.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=rCell, DefaultVersion:=8)
    With oPT
        .PivotFields("IDF").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("Raison").Orientation = xlColumnField
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("Fréquence"), "Sum of F", xlSum
    End With
    FeuilleName.Shapes.AddChart2(297, xlColumnStacked).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=oPT.TableRange1
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementLegendRight)

